MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED when connecting Node.js app with MongoDB running on Docker
Docker-compose file looks like this
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "2617:2716"
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    depends_on:
      - mongo

.env file looks like this
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
DB_HOST=mongo
DB_PORT=2617
DB_NAME=ptcgp

And I connect through this string:
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME + ':' 
  + process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD + '@' 
  + process.env.DB_HOST + ':' 
  + process.env.DB_PORT + '/' 
  + process.env.DB_NAME + '?retryWrites=true&writeConcern=majority&authSource=admin';
mongoose.connect(mongoURI);

mongoURI looks like this: mongodb://root:root@mongo:2617/ptcgp?retryWrites=true&writeConcern=majority&authSource=admin which looks correct to me...
It returns the following error: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:2617 and MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. but the MongoDB container is running.
I am doing the same exact thing with another project running in Docker with the ports set as 2717:27017 (thus the choices of the ports in this deploy) and it is working.

When containers on the same bridge network talk to each other, they don't use host mapped ports. I would expect that you should talk to it on port 27017. I don't know why you map the port you do. But if it is in fact listening on port 2716 that is the port you need to connect to.

You mean setting DB_PORT=2716 in the .env file? Unfortunately I tried that already prior to posting without success. :(

I edited my comment. Try 27017.

This worked, thank you very much! I spent some time on this. Can you write a full reply so I can mark it as the solution? I didn't really get why I should not use the ports I am telling Docker to use when running the app :)

Just a note, Template literals would be easier and you should encode the password. Would be this one: mongoURI = \mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${encodeURIComponent(process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD)}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&writeConcern=majority&authSource=admin``

Mongo listens on port 27017 by default.
When containers talk to each other on the docker bridge network, they don't use the mapped ports. The mapped ports are for talking to containers from outside the bridge network. So if you only need to talk to a container from other containers, you don't need to map the port(s).
Since each container has it's own IP address, containers can use the same port numbers without problem. But when you map them to host ports, you need to make sure that the mapped port numbers don't clash.
So to map the Mongo port to host port 2617 you should do
ports:
  - "2617:27017"

But since port 2617 would only be used for accessing Mongo from outside the Docker network, you should use port 27017 from your webapp.

Thank you so much! In the end I kept the ports "weird" in the DockerCompose file, and modifying my DB_PORT in the .env file like so: DB_PORT=27017 it fixed the problem. Very confusing, but now it is more clear - it is how Docker containers talk to each other wrt. how we talk to containers from the outside.
